# Send PNG image data to server to send email message

Tags: jsf, png, jqplot

I have JSF page that displays some PNG charts made with the Javascript library jqplot.

I'm required to send these images as an email with some other data. I usually use JavaMail for sending emails, but I have no idea how to send the displayed PNG images back to the server so I can attach them to the email message.

I've located the PNG image but I'm having problems on how to pass it to the backing bean and how to retreive it server side so I can attach it to an email message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compose image server side ;-)

Comment: Yeah to be honest I have been doing that with jfreechart and then attaching the created picture to the email, but I was looking for a way to use the same image that jqplot created.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. At which step exactly are you stucking? Finding the jQplot-generated PNG image in the HTML DOM tree? Or passing it or its URL back to the server side in some way? Or retrieving it in the server side? Or attaching it to an email? Etc. Ask a question about specifically that.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I edited my question to better represent my problem

Comment: Some code that you're working with would be a good place to start

Comment: Assume that he can create a png of the charts clientside, the important question would be, how to send the png data to the backing bean.